# Exercise 4, Section 6.6 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, projection, linear-independence

**Definition:** (1) Let $W_1,…,W_k$ be subspaces of the vector space $V$. We say that $W_1,…,W_k$ are independent if $\alpha_1+…+\alpha_n=0$, where $\alpha_i\in W_i$, then each $\alpha_i$ is $0$.

(2) If $V$ is a vector space, a projection of $V$ is a linear operator $E$ on $V$ such that $E^2 = E$.

---

> If $E_1$ and $E_2$ are projections onto independent subspaces, then $E_1 + E_2$ is a projection. True or false?

This problem is vague for me. I don’t know exactly what I have to do. I don’t understand “$E_1$ and $E_2$ are projections onto independent subspaces” sentence. Can you please rephrase this problem?

Comment: Please include definitions of projection and of independent subspace used in Hoffman.

Comment: @coffeemath I have edited by post to include relevant definition.

Comment: What's vague about it? You know what independent spaces are. You know what a projection is. What's missing?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I don’t understand “$E_1$ and $E_2$ are projections onto independent subspace” sentence.

Comment: $(E_1 + E_2)^2 = E_1^2 + E_1E_2 + E_2E_1 + E_2^2 = E_1 + E_2$, where we used the fact that $E_1E_2 = 0$ (due to independence) and by the definition of a projector $E_1^2 = E_1, E_2^2 = E_2$, so you get that $E_1 + E_2$ is indeed a projector.

Comment: @tortue Thank you for answer. From your solution I understand problem statement. Let me know if I’m correct. $E_1 , E_2 :V\to V$ are linear operator such that $E_1 , E_2$ are projection. Let image of $E_1, E_2$ are $W_1$, $W_2$, respectively. We are given $W_1$, $W_2$ are independent. Hoffman’s used word “onto” to denote image of $E_i$. We usually use onto for surjective map. Map $E_i:V\to E_i(V)$ is certainly surjective.

Comment: The definition of "independent" spaces is most likely: $X$ and $Y$ are independent iff $X\cap Y = \{0\}$. The comment by tortue is thus wrong. $E_1+E_2$ is a projector iff $E_1E_2=E_2E_1 = 0$. But having $R(E_1)\cap R(E_2)=\{0\}$ does not generally imply that $E_1E_2  = E_2E_1 = 0$. The matrices $E_1 = \begin{pmatrix}-2 & 1\\6 & 3\end{pmatrix}$ and $E_2 = \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0 &1\end{pmatrix}$ clearly demonstrate this (they are both projections and their ranges are independent).

Comment: @V.S.e.H. You’re correct. We (Reza Rajaei and I) realise the same thing ($R(E_1)\cap R(E_2)=\{0\}$ don’t generally imply $E_1E_2=E_2E_1=0$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is **FALSE**.

According to the book, a projection **on $R$ along $N$** means that $R$ is the range of the projection and $N$ is the null space.

Now, define $E_1$ as below:

$$E_1(1,-1)=(1, -1) , \ E_1(1,2)=(0,0);$$

so $E_1$ is a projection on the subspace spanned by $(1,-1)$, and moreover, $E_1(1,0)=(\frac {2}{3}, \frac{-2}{3})$, $E_1(0,1)=(\frac{-1}{3},\frac{1}{3}).$

Similarly, let's define:

$$E_2(1,0)=(1, 0) , \ E_2(0,1)=(0,0);$$
so $E_2$ is a projection on the subspace spanned by $(1,0).$

Observe that the subspaces spanned by $(1,-1)$ and $(1,0)$ are independent, regarding the definition of the book.

Now, you can easily check that:

$$(E_1+E_2)(1,-1)\neq (E_1+E_2)^2(1,-1).$$

---

**PS:** I took this example from [this online solution book, Exercise 6.6.4](https://linearalgebras.com/hoffman-kunze-chapter-6-6.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Problem statement is so damm vague that [this](https://christangdt.home.blog/2020/04/10/linear-algebra-2ed-hoffman-kunze-6-6/) solution reach to a different conclusion, i.e. statement is true. Also I don’t get the terminology of “projection on $R$ along $N$”. Well any linear operator has range and null space.

Comment: @user264745 Hello. You're welcome. About the solution you mentioned, it is not known that the range of one of the two projections is the null space of the other one and vice versa. You can simply see that the example I wrote is a counterexample to that calim. About the terminology, it is supposed to determine the range and null spaces of a projection. You can check the definitions in the book to realize how/why the example above was defined as it is. In this sense, everything is clear.

Comment: Yaa. You have made a nice point: we don’t know range of one of the two projections is contained in the null space of the other one and vice versa. That means my last comment (below post) of so called I understood problem statement is completely wrong, because we can’t conclude $E_1E_2=0$. But user tortue commented $E_1E_2=0$ (due to independence). What is that mean?

Comment: @user264745 Maybe, they (the answer in the comments above and the manual solution you mentioned) had different perceptions of being independent.